# Big Query Timeout in Metabase

Tags: google-bigquery, metabase

Hey guys I have trouble on querying BQ.
I have query that could be executed using BQ UI but always or rather often timeout in Metabase.

Do you have any idea how to optimize BQ querying performance in Metabase?

Thanks.

Comment: do you have a connection string there? usually adding `".....;timeout=3600"` is a way

Comment: Related https://github.com/metabase/metabase/issues/1749

Comment: Where do you put `".....;timeout=3600"` ?

Comment: Related with http://discourse.metabase.com/t/bigquery-questions-timeout/4157/3